# Php or Jquery How to check if image is save on browser?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to load the 3 image if the website has been view for the first time.
Because I have 3 page with full screen image. When I browse to the 2nd page I don't want to wait to load the large image.

And if I hit ctrl f5 the image will load again because the images will be cleared.

I try this code:

```
//css:
.load{
     display:none;
}
//Php:
    if(isset($_COOKIE["img"])){

    }else{
         setcookie("img", "load", time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
         echo '<img class="load" src="assets/images/DY8A0296-2400pix.jpg" alt="" />
                  <img class="load" src="assets/images/DY8A8350-2400pix.jpg" alt="" />';
     }
```

But when I hit ctrl 5 the Cookie is not delete.

Comment: You can use `preloader` js for preloading images.

Comment: ok I will check it out

Comment: you shouldn't use cookie to hold that value! best way is using js to load as @Anup said